# How to receive tag pressed event using tagListView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I'm using cocoa pod of `TagListView` https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView. And I need to catch the tagPressed event. I know that I should implement the delegate `TagListViewDelegate`, but I don't know where and how. Sorry for bad eng.

Here's my code

```
import UIKit
import TagListView

class MoreInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tagListView: TagListView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func addTagButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard tagNameTextField.text != "" else { return }
        let tagName = tagNameTextField.text!
        tagNameTextField.text = ""
        tagListView.addTag(tagName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting directly from the documentation,

> You can implement `TagListViewDelegate` to receive tag pressed event:

```
// ...
{
    // ...
    tagListView.delegate = self
    // ...
}

func tagPressed(title: String, tagView: TagView, sender: TagListView) {
    print("Tag pressed: \(title), \(sender)")
}
```

Simply define your delegate and place the function within the controller and touch events should be called to this function.